# Combing two text files together and zipping them

Tags: java

I AM NOT LOOKING FOR A CODE but and idea on how to approach the problem.

I have multiple text files with the following format

`NAME_EMAIL_CONTROL_DATE.txt
NAME_EMAIL_CONTROL2_DATE.txt`

I want to zip both the files given the DATE.

I am not sure how I can approach the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I don't know what you mean by "combine", nor what the similar date has to do with anything. There's no clear question here.

Comment: @arcy. Sorry about that. I just edited my question. Hope that helps

Comment: @Mani Your question is still unclear.  Perhaps you could provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If date is being stored at a specific constant spot on all the files (beginning of file, end of file) you can use a FileInputStream to read those specific bits into a buffer and check if the two contain the same data, which you could then continue to use said FileInputStream to read the contents of both into buffers and use a FileOutputStream to create your new combination file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you mean is that the file NAMES all have dates in them, at the end of their filename 'stems'...

Write a function to make a list of all your files -- given a directory containing the files, use `listFiles()` to get a list of all of them and compare the date portion to whatever you want, ending up with a list.

Then for each such file, use the zip file creation facility in java to add each file.

If all of these are in one directory, the command line zip command to do this will be fairly trivial, the hardest part will be the regular expression for the filename.